# JS. Не совсем понятен вывод. Обработка событий клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, события, клавиатура, javascript-events

Нужно проверить выводится ли цифра или иной символ. Пытался и циклом проверить вместо перечисления цифр, и таким вот длинным способом. Всё равно всё "true" вылазит, что бы не нажал. В чём проблема? Не первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь, что вроде по логике верно, а итог не понятен. Я пока только учусь, подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" class="i-3">


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector(".i-3").onkeypress = function f3(e) {
    // console.log(e);

    if (e.key == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }

};
```

Comment: `console.log([...Array(10).keys()].includes(+e.key, 1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector(".i-3").onkeypress = function f3(e) {
    console.log(e.key);

    if (["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"].indexOf(e.key) != -1) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-3">
```

```js
document.querySelector(".i-3").onkeypress = function f3(e) {
  console.log(e.key);

  var keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i] == e.key) {
      console.log(true);
      return;
    }
  }

  console.log(false);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-3">
```

```js
document.querySelector(".i-3").onkeypress = function f3(e) {
  console.log(e.key, typeof e.key);

  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (i == e.key) {
      console.log(true);
      return;
    }
  }

  console.log(false);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-3">
```

Comment: Пока не знал про этот метод. Спасибо, почитаю. А обязательно ли цифры как строки должны быть записаны? Нельзя ли как то сравнить всё это циклом? Например не строгим сравнением "==" или чем то подобным? Вдруг в будущем придётся делать сравнение бОльшей выборки, чем от 0 до 9.

Comment: @Павел Я не понял, что Вам надо.

Comment: Не могли бы объяснить отчего у меня всё время true выходило) А вообще хотел чтобы не приходилось вручную заполнять от 0 до 9 к примеру выборку. А задать цикл от и до. Без строк с цифрами и прочего, чтобы цикл сам подставлял числа, после чего проверял их, входят ли они в нужные мне параметры)) Как то так. Например мне нужно от 0 до 65. Не буду же я делать строку и вписывать вручную всё. Вот я к чему)

Comment: @Павел Потому что булевское представление чисел неравных нулю - `true`. То есть Ваше условие в `if` эквивалентно: `e.key == 1 || true || true ...`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, видимо не дотягиваю в знаниях пока. всё равно не понял) Подставляю буквы, а равняется всё true. Но ваш способ работает, спасибо) Всё равно новые знания, новые методы))

Comment: @Павел Куда Вы подставляете буквы? Мне сквозь монитор плохо виден Ваш код.

Comment: Всё прекрасно) Третий вариант кода мне прям запал)) Я что-то подобное писал, но не выходило изначально, а тут он выглядит и просто и прекрасно. И работает Я вот теперь думаю. Что же я писал такого, что у меня ничего не вышло) Вроде всё тоже самое =) Спасибо) Возможно я return не писал, или пытался break'ом выйти из цикла, и что-то несуразное выходило, а этот вариант всех хорош)

Comment: @Павел На здоровье. Успехов!